# Count overexposed pixels in image columns

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing

I have large data sets of grayscale images of 1024*2048 pixels.

What is a fast method to count the number of overexposed pixels in image columns?

The following example shows what I did:

```
SeedRandom[1];
imageData = RandomInteger[255, {100, 200}];
image = Image[imageData, "Byte"]
```

[image]

```
n = Count[#, value_ /; value == 255] & /@ Transpose@imageData;

ListPlot[n, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"row", "overexposed pixels per column"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Using `Count` without the `conditional` (/;) seems to be 30 x faster. `Count[#, 255] & /@ Transpose@imageData;`

Comment: @Anjan Kumar: Thanks. Put it into an answer. This is really much faster. In your solution the `Transpose` itself takes much more time than the counting.

Comment: Check the new version which is faster and avoids transpose operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**
A faster version using Vectorized operations.

```
Total[UnitStep[imageData - 255]];// AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0000731023, Null}

--

Using [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count.html) without the conditional (/;) is 30 x faster.

```
Count[#, 255] & /@ Transpose@imageData;// AbsoluteTiming
Count[#, value_ /; value == 255] & /@ Transpose@imageData;// AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000198258, Null}
>
> {0.00582259, Null}

Comment: Thanks. This is great.